# radio button not working when jquery append is used

Tags: jquery, html

I have an add button.On clicking it i want to generate multiple input fields such as radio button and date picker.for that i am using jquery append functionality.I was able to generate multiple fields but my radio butto is not working properly.can anyone help me with this.

Please have a look at my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmfkb1j3/)

Here is my code:

```js
$('body').on('focus', ".datepicker", function() {
  $(this).datepicker();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  var id = 1;
  var idt = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      id++;
      idt++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="input-line-control removeMe"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><div class="radio-group"><input type="radio" id="id" name="S_gender" checked><label class="radioLabel" for="id">Male</label><input type="radio" id="idt" name="S_gender"><label class="radioLabel" for="idt">female</label></div></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="date"></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-danger remove-date"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>Remove</button></div></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove-date", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('div.removeMe').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```css
.myDate {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.radioLabel {
  color: #9a929e;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3c7ab7;
}

.radio-group {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 0px 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap Dynamic DatePicker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- Include Bootstrap Datepicker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.min.css" />

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-12">

    <button class="btn btn-primary add_field_button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add More</button>
  </div>


  <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <!-- Dynamic Fields go here -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is because you are using the `id` tag and the id tag cant be same for more than one elements in a DOM

Comment: The full content of your question must be in your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to create one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio button should have unique ids and name to work properly, here is code I have update for you...

```
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    var id = 1;
     var idt = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    var rdio=$('.input_fields_wrap input[type=radio]').length;
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
             id++;
             idt++; 
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="input-line-control removeMe"><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><div class="radio-group"><input type="radio" id="id_'+rdio+'" name="S_gender_'+rdio+'" checked><label class="radioLabel" for="id_'+rdio+'">Male</label><input type="radio" id="idt_'+rdio+'" name="S_gender_'+rdio+'"><label class="radioLabel" for="idt_'+rdio+'">female</label></div></div></div><div class="col-md-5"><div class="form-group"><input type="date"></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><button class="btn btn-danger remove-date"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>Remove</button></div></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove-date", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest('div.removeMe').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

I have also updated the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/hka3ugos/